# Boolean functions

Tags: boolean-algebra

Boolean function f(x1,x2,x3):

If

`f(x1,x2,x3)= TRUE`

then

`f(TRUE,x2,x3)= TRUE`

`f(x1,TRUE,x3)= TRUE`

`f(TRUE,TRUE,x3)= TRUE`

`f(x1,x2,TRUE)= TRUE`

`f(TRUE,x2,TRUE)= TRUE`

`f(x1,TRUE,TRUE)= TRUE`

`f(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)= TRUE`

For 2 arguments there is 6 such functions. How many such functions for N arguments?

What is the class of these function called?

---

Edit:
For N=2 variables, these are the functions:

```
A   B|  F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  F6
0   0|  0   0   0   0   0   1
0   1|  0   0   0   1   1   1
1   0|  0   0   1   0   1   1
1   1|  0   1   1   1   1   1
```

F1(a,b) = False

F2(a,b) = A & B

F3(a,b) = A

F4(a,b) = B

F5(a,b) = A or B

F6(a,b) = True

Comment: Really $6$? You wrote down $7$ (or $8$ with initial). There is $2^N$ rows in truth table; but I'm not sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: see edit. It is functions where if the result is true, then changing arbitrary false variables to true, the result must stay true.

Comment: It's completely unclear. What is $F1$? If $f(x, y)$ is a function, and $f(x,\, false) = f(x,\, true)$, then $f(x, y)$ actually doesn't depend on $y$. Since you want to demand it for any variable, your functions are constant. Anyway, clarify your question.

Comment: F1 is the first 2-variable function that satisfies it.

Comment: Well, and what is truth table for $F1$?

Comment: see edit. Please also note that XOR function doesn't belong to this class.

Comment: In your question you neglect to state what condition "such" functions are supposed to satisfy. However, from a comment of yours, I guess you are asking about [monotone Boolean functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number). Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly some background issues,
Boolean function is same just like other mathematical function **f: (B^n)--->B , provided B={0,1} is a boolean domain and n is non-negative #** .
Boolean function of 1 variable can have 2 values 0 and 1.
and with 0 var either it'll be 0 or 1, completely constant with no logical operations.

Similarly **a boolean function of n var can have 2^n combinations of values**.
eg:- 3 var boolean functions can have 2^3 elements (all from 0 to 7 in binary.... 000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111)

now monotone boolean function . First understand the word monotone, which means either it is going up (increasing) or down (decreasing).

[(1) shows increasing ; 2 shows decreasing; 3 is a constant y(that line is parallel to x axis) ; 4th  shows increment and decrement both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX7LC.png)

Now coming to MBF (Monotone Boolean Function) : Function in which the value of the function follows the value of arguments. Consider a monotonic function fm and <x1 , x2 , ....., xn> as well as <y1,  y2, .... , yn> as the sequence of the truth values :

if  <x1 , x2 , ....., xn> <= <y1,  y2, .... , yn>
then fm(x1 , x2 , ....., xn) <= fm(y1,  y2, .... , yn) .

To make this more sensible , consider F <T .

distributive lattice is a lattice which follows the distributive property

> ```
>    1. (x+(y.z))=((x.y)+(x.z))
>    2. (x.(y+z))=((x.y)+(x.z))
> ```

Now look at the boolean lattice below in the image . Boolean lattice is nothing but a distributive lattice with 0 and 1 in which every node / element has a complement (000 and 111 belongs to same lattice ). (0 is not equal to 1).

[3-tuple boolean lattice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgW39.png)

**Now answer to your question**

There's no function from F1 to F6 which satisfies this , except for F5 only. but if you consider 4- var function (input of values from the combination of A and B ) then from F1 to F6 they all are a part of MBFunction.

> Furthermore , MBFs can't be concluded without looking at the logical
> expressions . Therefore for the n-arguments you'll have to state the
> logical expression for it. Although i must tell you , **the # of MBFs
> in an n var is called nth Dedekind # .  Its' calculation is still a
> challenge for all of us**. For upto 8 variables only this is known.
> for upto n=6 , we know the in-equivalent MBFs.

*forgive me for the handmade images,in Img 1 , 3rd graph looks more of a non-constant but consider that line as parallel to x-axis*
*# means number*

(edit-reference)

```
    for reference, visit:
 https://www.sfu.ca/~tstephen/Papers/r7.pdf
```

Thanks.